# Detect interesting testcases

Tags: binary-analysis, dynamic-analysis, instrumentation, fuzzing

Suppose I have a ton of test cases and my target is closed-source. Well, I need to know which test cases discover new path in the execution of my target and which are duplicated. I know I have to use DBI frameworks such as [DynamoRIO](https://www.dynamorio.org/), [Intel Pin](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pin-a-dynamic-binary-instrumentation-tool) and others. But, I cannot figure out how to use them, in the other words, I got confused to how I should save trace map and check them for a ton of test cases!?

Another question is, how can we figure out a test case is good and interesting during fuzzing test? Just discovering new path?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to discover new test cases (or check that a test case is valuable) on a binary, the good way to go is to use tools such as [KLEE](https://klee.github.io/) (see this [small tutorial](https://klee.github.io/tutorials/testing-function/)).

The point is too use [symbolic execution](http://www.sti.uniurb.it/events/sfm14esm/slides/albert.pdf) to try to cover a maximum of the possible execution paths which are in the binary.

So, I would advise you to take a deeper look at the [symbolic execution approach](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~weimerw/2011-6610/reading/p213-godefroid.pdf).

Comment: Although symbolic execution is *one way* of measuring the value of test cases, it is not the only one. For example, coverage measures are also a valid approach (that fits OPs intentions of using a dynamic instrumentation tools).

Comment: AFL comes to mind ...

Comment: yes, definitely!